# Lightbox to appear over frames

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox, frames, frameset

I have a problem with site I'm adding functionality to, unfortunately it has a frameset with a number of frames within it. I want to make my lightbox appear above all the frames, full screen - is there a way I can do this? The lightbox will be launched from one of the child frames. I have full access to the code but cannot use iframes except for the lightbox itself.

Thanks,
Colin.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot (because the frames are different pages).

Comment: Could I add an additional frame to the frameset and launch it from that or similar?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to split the lightbox into each of the frames, so that all the frames together look like one seamless overlay.

Otherwise, the overlay will only apply to the frame that it is in.

Comment: I found that the other option for me is to dynamically resize the frameset to make one screen fullscreen and then launch the lightbox there.

Thanks